# unpredictable behaviour of threads

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to implement this simple example of how to synchronize threads using pthread library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std ;

static pthread_mutex_t locker;
pthread_cond_t cond;
volatile bool ok=false;


void *func2(void *data)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&locker);
    cout << "1";
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
    if(i==10)
    {
        ok=true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    }

}

pthread_exit(0);

  }

void *fun1(void *data)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{

    if(ok==false){
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &locker);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock (&locker);
    cout << "2";
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
}

pthread_exit(0);
   }




   int main(void)
  {


pthread_t thread1, thread2;
void *retour_thread;


pthread_mutex_init (&locker, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

if(pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, fun1, NULL) < 0)
{
    cout << "problem thread";
    exit(1);
}
if(pthread_create (&thread2, NULL, func2, NULL) < 0)
{
    cout << "problem thread";
    exit(1);
}


(void)pthread_join(thread1,&retour_thread);
(void)pthread_join(thread2,&retour_thread);

return 0;
    }
```

what should I see is func1 wait until the condition (ok==true) then process func2...but what I'm getting is unpredictable and not synchrinised!!!

any help and thanks in advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to acquire the mutex before you call pthread_cond_wait, and after pthread_cond_wait returns, the mutex is reacquired. Your fun1() should look something like:

```
void *fun1(void *data)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&locker);
        if(ok==false)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &locker);

        cout << "2";
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
    }
}
```

Update:

You have a race where func2() can signal faster than fun1() can consume. If you want alternate "1" and "2" outputs, you need feedback in both directions.

Comment: This causes a deadlock. He also needs to not acquire the lock in fun2.

Comment: thanks for answer..but stil can't get what I want....thebehaviour is random!!! you can try it to see....by the way I'm on Windows

Comment: @Benubird: pthread_cond_wait releases the lock atomically, that's why you need to pass the lock

Comment: 111111111111111222222222222222222.....2222222222222111..1111111 and that's random...what i want is this...1(10 times)212121212121..2(10 times).till the end

Comment: @fsidiosidi: then you have to program the threads to have this behaviour.  Threads are independent of each other, but they can communicate, as you did now to let one thread wait until the other tells him to start.  You didn't tell them to wait until the other has looped.

Comment: @fsidiosidi: just based on this example: you actually don't want parallel behaviour (which is not predictable in order), you want sequential behaviour which should be done in 1 thread.

Comment: @janm: there is no race.  Both threads get their timeslice in which they just loop.  It is just made sure that fun1 doesn't start looping until func2 has looped 11 times

Comment: @stefaanv: The race is in terms of the requirement that the output "1" and "2" alternate. I agree they just loop.

Comment: @janm: The code should actually be `while (ok == false)`, not `if()` (spurious wakeups are allowed, and in the general case you might have multiple consumers anyway, so it's best just to remember the `while()`).

Answer (score 1):

- Rule number 1 for condition
  variables: wait on condition variable
  while holding the lock (while waiting
  the lock will be released)
- Rule number 2 for condition
  variables: always use "while
  condition, wait for condition
  variable" (avoiding spurious signals)

Answer (score 0):

My experience with pthread_cond_wait is that it does then to be a little unpredictable. There are a few things you can try though.

For instance, instead of using if(ok == false) try using while(ok==false), so that it repeats the wait if something causes it to return early (always good practice). Consider also that there is no consistency in how long a thread will run for - for example, it is entirely possible that thread1 will yield immediately after returning from the wait, which is going to give you some unpredictable results... Try posting what happens so we can examine it in more detail.

Also, do what janm said ;)

Comment: 111111111111111222222222222222222.....2222222222222111..1111111 and that's random...what i want is this...1(10 times)212121212121..2(10 times).till the end